# How to search a value in a column a..obtain its row count and paste in column b in front of all rows till it was found..again continue the same

Tags: microsoft-excel

```
Column a    Column b
#abd        Request This is to be copied
#pqr        Request This is to be copied
#lmn        Request This is to be copied
Request This is to be copied    
#abdq       Request This is row 2 to be copied
#pqrw       Request This is row 2 to be copied
#lmn2       Request This is row 2 to be copied
#qqq        Request This is row 2 to be copied
Request This is row 2 to be copied  0
```

In the start only `Column a` is populated. For all rows in `Column b` beginning with `#`, `Column b` should be populated until a string starting with `Request` is found. This is put up in `Column b`.

Whereever string starts with `Request` is to be copied in front of the rows until it was found. Again reset and start the process again.

Hope I have been able to explain the idea.

Answer (score 1):

You could perhaps use this formula and then drag it down:

```
=IF(LEFT(A1,1)="#",IF(LEFT(A2,7)="Request",A2,B2),IF(LEFT(A1,7)="Request","",A1))
```

This function makes sure that the line with `Request` is also empty. If you don't mind having it also copied, then you can use this shorter one:

```
=IF(LEFT(A1,1)="#", B2, IF(A2="Request*",A1))
```

Put those in `A1` then drag down.